# How to implement different languages on html page

Tags: javascript, html, multilingual

I am just a newcomer developing an app with html/css/js via phonegap. I've been searching info on how to make my app be displayed in different languages and Google doesn't understand me. 
So the idea is to have a button on index.html that let the user choose the language in which the app will be displayed, in this case Spanish/English, nothing strange like arabic blablabla....
So I guess that the solution must be related to transform all the text that I load in html to variables and then depending on the language selected display the correct one. I have no idea how to make this, and Im not able to find examples. So that's what Im asking for... if someone could give some code snipet to see how html variables works and how should I save user language selection...

Appreciated guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on the complexity of language-dependencies in the application. If you have just a handful of short texts in a strongly graphic application, you can just store the texts in JavaScript variables or, better, in properties of an object, with one object per language.

But if you expect to encounter deeper language-dependencies as well (e.g., displaying dynamically computed decimal numbers, which should be e.g. 1.5 in English and 1,5 in Spanish), then it’s probably better to use a library like [Globalize.js](https://github.com/jquery/globalize) (described in some detail in my book [Going Global with JavaScript and Globalize.js](http://www.bytelevelbooks.com/books/global_javascript.html)). That way you could use a unified approach, writing e.g. a string using `Globalize.localize('greeting')` and a number using `Globalize.format(x, 'n1')` and a date using `Globalize.format(date, 'MMM d')`.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by internationalization (such as i18N). To do this you need separate file for each language and put all your text in it. Search Google for internationalization.

Otherwise you can look into embeding Google Translate.